# Reading .txt file with UTF-8

Tags: android, utf-8, inputstream

I have a txt file that contains words with UTF-8 encoding. I put it in "assets" folder and this is a way I read them:

```
private void readWordsFromFile() {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    try {
        InputStream is = assetManager.open("words.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF8"));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            HashMap<String, String> tempMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            tempMap.put("question", line);
            line = reader.readLine();
            tempMap.put("answer", line);
            words.add(tempMap); // adding to an ArrayList
        }
        reader.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error during openin learning file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Then I take these words form array and I put them in TextViews. The layout xml file has specified UFT8 encoding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

But the are still displayed wrong. What am I doing not right?

Comment: "But the are still displayed wrong" -- please explain in greater detail what your exact symptoms are.

Comment: There are black squares instead of "ś", "ć" and "ę"

Comment: That may be a font issue.

Comment: `The layout xml file has specified UFT8 encoding:`. That is irrelevant as that specifies the encoding of the xml file. Not the behaviour of a TextView declared in it.

Comment: `a txt file that contains words with UTF-8 encoding.`. No. If it is a utf-8 text file then ALL words are in that encoding.

Comment: How many blocks do you see for a wrong character? One or two?

Comment: If you put those characters in the xml file in the text sting of those text views, are they displayed ok? Use EditText for a test and see if you can place and type them.

Comment: @greenapps one block. It looks fine when I put it directly in xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

I had to change the txt file encoding:

**assets folder -> my file -> right click -> properties -> change encoding to UTF8**